# What is proper abstraction using Entity Framework in webforms

Tags: asp.net, architecture, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to figure out a good way to architect my solution.  I know that I am going to be using the following technologies, Asp.Net Webforms, and Entity Framework 4.1.  My EF model is based on an existing database.  I'm planning to use the EF DbContext generator to build my context and entities.  And this is the point where things get a little tricky for me.

I want to have proper separation of concerns, providing for better testability and allowing me to separate my business logic from my DAL.  I have three projects in my solution currently: Web, Core, and Data.  I would like dependencies to be Web -> Core <- Data, with no dependency between Web and Data at all.  This requires my entities to actually exist in Core, rather than Data (where my edmx is).  Currently, my thought is to move the Entities.tt file to Core and change the inputFile to point to my edmx in Data to generate my Entities in Core.  But I'm unsure what to do with the Context.  It's heavily dependent on EF and therefore I don't simply want to move that into Core.  I thought about interfacing it, creating my own IEntities.Context.tt and dropping that in Core.  My concern is the loss of functionality if my interface doesn't create DbSets and DbContext.

Two thoughts I've been having on this are, 1) put a ref to System.Data.Entity in Core, 2) don't use DbSet and replace it with ICollection (or some such generic container) and wrap DbContext as just an Object in my interface.

Any insight would be very appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you let the context and Context.tt generator leave in your Data project? I don't see a need to move it into Core. Core must reference the context in your Data library of course. Is that the problem you are having and what you don't want? If so, you are going to add a whole additional level of complexity and abstraction to your application because you must abstract EF away from your Core (abstract "repository" and "unit of work" pattern is the usual way to do this = the keywords to search for). Things get much easier if Core references Data though.

Comment: I was thinking that Core shouldn't be dependent on Data at all, but rather provide basic POCO objects that both Data and Web could use.  This completely decouples Web from Data and allows for the potential of Data to be swapped out more easily (ie: if we were to want move to nHibernate or another ORM).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different patterns you could use, but two come to mind immediately:

1) Add a business / service layer - this will abstract between your data layer and your presentation layer. This is the approach I take most often - using AutoMapper and Dependency Injection (I like Ninject) to make the monkey work easier. Your business layer would expose either its own version of your database objects (not recommended), or objects which related to your business model (a more robust approach).

2) Use the Inversion of Control pattern - Very popular at the moment, though I'm yet to give it a bash in a real life scenario. Apparently very good for TDD / mocking etc... it basically means that your data layer has a dependency on your business layer instead of the other way around.

FYI - My "Core" or "Common" assemblies know nothing about my business or data layers - they merely provide platform agnostic helpers and common classes - if I want to create common MVC functionality, for example, I'll create a Company.MVC.Core assembly instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your solution is completely greenfield then I like to use a code first approach in entity framework (forgive the shameless plug but I've put a tutorial on my blog about this http://www.terric.co.uk/code-first-entity-framework-and-sql-migrations/).  I like the control it gives me that I can't seem to get when I generate a .edmx.

Moving onto structure, I usually separate the layers of my project into separate assemblies: Domain (and Data) and WebUI structured with the following folders (namespaces):

```
Domain (business layer and data layer assembly)
    Data (contains my EF data context and Interface to the context)
    Entities (contains my POCO objects for the context)

WebUI (presentation layer assembly)
    Infrastructure (contains my dependency inject initialiser)
```

I never DI my entities and instead use the concretes in my presentation layer, however the context I'll always DI as I may want / have to use ADO.Net (especially for legacy apps) where my Domain layer will still use ADO.Net to read / write my POCO entities.  This way, when I eventually get scope to implementing an ORM with my legacy app I can simply DI the ORM version of my Domain.

As a footnote to this, if you were following the repository pattern you could always interface them and DI your repositories.  Either way, your POCOs should be specific to the solution so the underlying data structure doesn't dramatically change often hence I never DI them.